# Javascript confirm with PHP function afterward

Tags: php, javascript, confirm

I would like a way to have a confirm box pop up when a user clicks "delete" to remove a record.

Something like:

```
<script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript" >

function confirmDelete() {
    if(confirm("Would you like to delete the selected products?")) {
        <?php 
            $allCheckBoxId = $_POST['checkbox'];
            array_map ('mysql_real_escape_string', $allCheckBoxId);
            $ids = implode(",", $allCheckBoxId);
            $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE `id` IN ($ids)";
            mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
    }
}

</script>
```

With an onclick:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete'  onclick='confirmDelete()' />";
```

But I know it's not possible to be using Javascript & PHP together like this. Is there another way to do this? Maybe PHP has its own kind of confirm? Please give any ideas!

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is pretty easy to make use of AJAX for this case. Simply place your PHP in the `scriptDelete.php` file and make sure you pass the proper arguments and their values in the `data` property. For this example I just pass an **id** of **5**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function confirmDelete() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
            //Make ajax call
            $.ajax({
                url: "scriptDelete.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id : 5},
                dataType: "html", 
                success: function() {
                    alert("It was succesfully deleted!");
                }
            });

        }
    }
</script>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete'  onclick='return confirmDelete()' />
```

Another way would be to post the form back to its own page like:

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')" />
</form>
```

So you simply post the form back to `yourpage.php` and on top of this page you do something like:

```
<?php

   //Means the form was submitted
   if ($_POST['submit']) {
      $id = $_POST['idToDelete'];
      $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($id);
      mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should move the event to the form, and use onsubmit="confirmDelete()".  If you return false within the ConfirmDelete function, the form submit is cancelled.  If you return true, the form will get submitted like normal, and you can process it like a regular form on the server side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmDelete() {
    return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
}
</script>

<form action="myDelete.php" onsubmit="confirmDelete()">
    ....inputs
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Then have regular processing code on the server side

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do a javascript function before you submit. If you click on false, the return will be false and it will not be submitted:

```
<form action="something.php" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');" method="post">
// Fields
// Fields
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked & was the easiest to implement to what I already have.

Comment: @Catia: Do remember that inline eventhandlers are an anti-pattern though.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by anti-pattern?

Comment: Actually this will not work as I am also planning on adding an "Add" button. So when someone clicks add I would not like it to ask "are you sure?" Thanks though!

Comment: @Catia: In software engineering, an anti-pattern (or antipattern) is a pattern that may be commonly used but is ineffective and/or counterproductive in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to confirm, instead of creating whole new function.
Do this

```
<input type="submit" name="Delete" onClick='return confirm("Sure you want Delete this Page?")' />
```

this will exactly respond the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax. Place your php in a separate file, and use ajax to send it the id you want to use in your query. I recommend [jQuery .post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)